# Indexer model is not defined

Tags: indexing

I'm using Magento CE 1.7.
here is the error I get suddenly, each time I access the "index management" screen (so I canot access it anymore), or each time I try to update a product (so i can't save product anymore) and each time I try to enable/disable a module from the back end:

```
Indexer model is not defined. 

Trace:
#0 /home/webscoot/www/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(306): Mage::throwException('Indexer model is not defined.')
#1 /home/webscoot/www/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Block/Adminhtml/Process/Grid.php(72): Mage_Index_Model_Process->getIndexer()
#2 /home/webscoot/www/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Grid.php(534): Mage_Index_Block_Adminhtml_Process_Grid->_afterLoadCollection()
#3 /home/webscoot/www/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Block/Adminhtml/Process/Grid.php(62): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid->_prepareCollection()
#4 /home/webscoot/www/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Grid.php(626): Mage_Index_Block_Adminhtml_Process_Grid->_prepareCollection()
#5 /home/webscoot/www/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Grid.php(632): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid->_prepareGrid()
#6 /home/webscoot/www/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(862): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid->_beforeToHtml()
#7 /home/webscoot/www/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(582): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#8 /home/webscoot/www/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(526): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('grid', true)
#9 /home/webscoot/www/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Grid/Container.php(77): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('grid')
#10 /home/webscoot/www/app/design/adminhtml/base/default/template/widget/grid/container.phtml(36): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Container->getGridHtml()
#11 /home/webscoot/www/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/home/webscoot/www/app/design/adminhtml/base/default/template/widget/grid/container.phtml')
#12 /home/webscoot/www/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('adminhtml/base/default/template/widget/grid/container.phtml')
#13 /home/webscoot/www/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#14 /home/webscoot/www/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Template.php(81): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#15 /home/webscoot/www/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Container.php(308): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#16 /home/webscoot/www/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(863): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Container->_toHtml()
#17 /home/webscoot/www/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Text/List.php(43): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
```

etc

Comment: Did you find an answer here? Please mark it as solution.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Most probably you have a declared indexer that does not have a model associated to it.
There is also the chance that if you have the cache enabled, this cache can be corrupted. (but I doubt it). Just to make sure first you clear the contents of var/cache.
If that does not work, and probably won't here is how the indexes work. An index is defined in the `config.xml` of a module. Here is an example.

```
<index>
   <indexer>
        <catalog_product_attribute>
            <model>catalog/product_indexer_eav</model>
        </catalog_product_attribute> 
         ..............
    </indexer>
</index>
```

This declares an index with code `catalog_product_attribute`. As you can see there is a `model` tag inside it. That is the model that should handle the index. This is what is missing for one of your indexes.
To see which one is wrong do this:

In the method `Mage_Index_Model_Process::getIndexer()`, above the line:

```
Mage::throwException(Mage::helper('index')->__('Indexer model is not defined.'));
```

Add this debug line:

```
echo $code;exit;
```

and try to access the index grid again. This should show you the index with problems. Check the `config.xml` files for a tag with the same name as the value you get from the code above. Look specially in the extensions that you recently installed.

Comment: Once echoing $code, check the `index_process` table for stale indices that are no longer used. Removing an index from a module we previously uninstalled solved my problem.

Comment: Same here, disabling the "Mage_Tag" extension lead to its index being no longer available on one of our environments.

Answer (score -4):

Delete everything in var/ folder.
Refresh the cache...

It would work :)