# Cannot Access Magento Admin after Server move

Tags: magento-1.7, error, php, migration

I have install magento 1.7.0.2 on a new server and have copied the database from my old site on a different server, I have changed the core_config_data details to match and the site config. and the frontend works fine but when i go to log in it get the "there has been a error processing your request" and i have looked in to the generated log file and have got this.

```
a:5:{i:0;s:29:"Indexer model is not defined.";i:1;s:3293:"#0 /var/www/directory/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(309): Mage::throwException('Indexer model i...')
#1 /var/www/directory/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Block/Adminhtml/Notifications.php(41): Mage_Index_Model_Process->getIndexer()
#2 /var/www/directory/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/index/notifications.phtml(27): Mage_Index_Block_Adminhtml_Notifications->getProcessesForReindex()
#3 /var/www/directory/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/var/www/devkoo...')
#4 /var/www/directory/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('adminhtml/defau...')
#5 /var/www/directory/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#6 /var/www/directory/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Template.php(81): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#7 /var/www/directory/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Block/Adminhtml/Notifications.php(67): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#8 /var/www/directory/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(886): Mage_Index_Block_Adminhtml_Notifications->_toHtml()
#9 /var/www/directory/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Text/List.php(43): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#10 /var/www/directory/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(886): Mage_Core_Block_Text_List->_toHtml()
#11 /var/www/directory/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(605): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#12 /var/www/directory/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(549): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('notifications', true)
#13 /var/www/directory/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/page.phtml(55): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('notifications')
#14 /var/www/directory/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/var/www/devkoo...')
#15 /var/www/directory/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('adminhtml/defau...')
#16 /var/www/directory/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#17 /var/www/directory/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Template.php(81): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#18 /var/www/directory/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(886): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#19 /var/www/directory/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(555): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#20 /var/www/directory/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(390): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->getOutput()
#21 /var/www/directory/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/DashboardController.php(43): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->renderLayout()
#22 /var/www/directory/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Adminhtml_DashboardController->indexAction()
#23 /var/www/directory/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')
#24 /var/www/directory/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#25 /var/www/directory/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#26 /var/www/directory/app/Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#27 /var/www/directory/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#28 {main}";s:3:"url";s:78:"/directory/index.php/admin/dashboard/index/key/510a7eb9b1a6a51bbf0e20f99eab0850/";s:11:"script_name";s:18:"/directory/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:5:"admin";}
```

I have followed this [Indexer model is not defined](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/3294/indexer-model-is-not-defined) and i get "product" appearing  and i search through every config.xml file and cannot find anything which looks different, Has anyone had this before and how can i fix it.

Comment: I would try clearing the caches.

Comment: Try this, delete /var/www/directory/var/cache/ and /var/www/directory/var/locks/ to clear all the caches and index locks. Then go to /var/www/directory/shell/ and run 'php indexer.php reindexall' after reindexing try logging into the backend again.