# Exception printing is disabled by default for security reasons after failed log in attempts

Tags: error, login

I had trouble logging into the Magento admin panel, I failed to login correctly 3 times, on the fourth attempt I got the following error.

There has been an error processing your request
Exception printing is disabled by default for security reasons.

Error log record number: 1279920557761

Below is a copy of the error report.

Can somebody point me in the right direction as to what is wrong?

```
            a:5:{i:0;s:29:"Indexer model is not defined.";i:1;s:4721:"#0 /var/www/vhosts/example.com/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(311): Mage::throwException('Indexer model i...')
            #1 /var/www/vhosts/example.com/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Block/Adminhtml/Notifications.php(41): Mage_Index_Model_Process->getIndexer()
            #2 /var/www/vhosts/example.com/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/index/notifications.phtml(27): Mage_Index_Block_Adminhtml_Notifications->getProcessesForReindex()
            #3 /var/www/vhosts/example.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/var/www/vhosts...')
            #4 /var/www/vhosts/example.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('adminhtml/defau...')
            #5 /var/www/vhosts/example.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
            #6 /var/www/vhosts/example.com/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Template.php(81): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
            #7 /var/www/vhosts/example.com/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Block/Adminhtml/Notifications.php(67): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template->_toHtml()
            #8 /var/www/vhosts/example.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(923): Mage_Index_Block_Adminhtml_Notifications->_toHtml()
            #9 /var/www/vhosts/example.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Text/List.php(43): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
            #10 /var/www/vhosts/example.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(923): Mage_Core_Block_Text_List->_toHtml()
            #11 /var/www/vhosts/example.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(641): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
            #12 /var/www/vhosts/example.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(585): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('notifications', true)
            #13 /var/www/vhosts/example.com/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/page.phtml(55): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('notifications')
            #14 /var/www/vhosts/example.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/var/www/vhosts...')
            #15 /var/www/vhosts/example.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('adminhtml/defau...')
            #16 /var/www/vhosts/example.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
            #17 /var/www/vhosts/example.com/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Template.php(81): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
            #18 /var/www/vhosts/example.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(923): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template->_toHtml()
            #19 /var/www/vhosts/example.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(555): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
            #20 /var/www/vhosts/example.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(390): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->getOutput()
            #21 /var/www/vhosts/example.com/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/DashboardController.php(43): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->renderLayout()
            #22 /var/www/vhosts/example.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Adminhtml_DashboardController->indexAction()
            #23 /var/www/vhosts/example.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(254): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')
            #24 /var/www/vhosts/example.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
            #25 /var/www/vhosts/example.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(365): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
            #26 /var/www/vhosts/example.com/app/Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
            #27 /var/www/vhosts/example.com/index.php(83): Mage::run('', 'store')
            #28 {main}";s:3:"url";s:73:"/index.php/ts_admin/dashboard/index/key/ce7cfc51cc5db517fd53a5b2a650c576/";s:11:"script_name";s:10:"/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:5:"admin";}
```

Answer (score 1):

try clear your cache, if this will not helps check this question
according to your error
- [Indexer model is not defined](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/3294/indexer-model-is-not-defined)

Comment: clearing my browser cache didn't work, that what you meant?

Comment: I se what you mean now, thanks, clearing var/cache folder worked :)

Comment: yes, magento cache)

Comment: ahh. the problem came back again. After navigating away from the dashboard the error came back :(

Comment: i found this message in dashboard:

One or more of the Indexes are not up to date: Product Attributes, Product Prices, Catalog URL Rewrites, Product Flat Data, Category Flat Data, Category Products, Catalog Search Index, Stock Status, Tag Aggregation Data. Click here to go to Index Management and rebuild required indexes.